# Executing a method call in a PLINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running a small test on a WCF service, so I'm loading up 1000 accounts, and for each I want to call a method that returns an object.  I'm missing something here, as the runAccount method is never called.

```
 private static void RunTest()
    {
        var accounts = CsvHelper.ParseCsv(@"Data\acccounts.csv");

        GeneralHelper.MemberData = (from a in accounts.AsParallel()
                                    select runAccount(a)) as IList<MemberFormDataContract>; //PLINQ
    }


    private static MemberFormDataContract runAccount(Account acct)
    {
        IAccountMasterService accountMasterService = new AccountMasterServiceClient();
        MemberFormDataContract memberFormDataContract = accountMasterService.FindMemberFormByAccountId(acct.Id);
        return memberFormDataContract;
    }
```

the point here is that I want to run the call for each account in the list, and populate a helper class with the results that is timing the calls and looking for high/low and an average.  the problem is that the actual call to the service is never made, which helps the number look fantastic, but totally bogus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `as IList<MemberFormDataContract>` by `ToList()`. The execution of your `select` statement is deferred until you force it to be executed by (e.g.) ToList().

Comment: Well, this is proof to me that rushing the simplest of things on a Sunday afternoon just wastes time.  Thanks.

Comment: The return value assigned to GeneralHelper.MemberData is pobably null.
Also keep in mind that the query will only be executed as you consume the data from GeneralHelper.MemberData. Do not expect it to execute after you jumped over the line in debugger.

Comment: LOL, worse, it's sunday night here.

Comment: @ achitaka-san thanks, PLINQ is new to me as of 1 hour ago.  I'm used to grappling with the TPL so I figured this would be a nice break for a quickie on getting load/speed times.  Thanks.

Comment: You would have seen the exact same effect without the `AsParallel`. This is simply about LINQ deferred execution.